# Google plus icon breaks line in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, opera

I have share buttons at the bottom of my page, looking ok in Chrome and Firefox:

[image]

In safari not so much:

[image]

In opera breaks too :

[image]

This is my HTML :

```
<div class="social">
              <div class='custom-tweeter-follow'>
                <a class="twitter-follow-button" href="https://twitter.com/mycompany" data-show-count='false'>Follow @mycompany</a>
              </div>
              <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/mycompany" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
              <div class='custom-gplus-follow'>
                <g:plusone size="medium" count="false" href='https://plus.google.com/xxx'></g:plusone>
              </div>
              <div syle='clear:both'></div>
</div>
```

This is my css:

```
.copyright {
  float: left
  line-height: 25px
  font-weight: 300
  font-size: 14px
  width: 240px
}

.custom-tweeter-follow {
    float: left
    margin: 5px 10px 0px 0px
}
.custom-gplus-follow {
    float: right
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? And how can I avoid things like this in the future, this should pretty much standard (sorry not a UI developer) what people are doing.

Comment: Does moving `custom-gplus-follow` to the beginning of `social` solve the problem? (Meaning put google button before tweeter & fb in the html)

Comment: Problem with float elements dropping a line is always because the total width & spacing of all element is greater than the container's width. I would make a wild guess that you're not using some thing like a normalizer to, well, normalize appearance across browsers, and the `body` turns out smaller on safari & opera because of the default margin around `body`.

Comment: @AvAvt yes moving `custom-gplus-follow` to the beginning solves the problem, please add answer I ll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so moving `custom-gplus-follow` to the beginning of `social` would solve the problem, since `float: right` elements need to come before others in the html to remain on the same row.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `float` as Av Avt mentioned, use `display: inline;` on each class like this:

```
.copyright {
  display: inline;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 240px;
}
.custom-tweeter-follow {
  display: inline;
  margin: 5px 10px 0px 0px;
}
.custom-gplus-follow {
  display: inline;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.fb-like {
  display: inline;
}
```